# 2checkout authorization failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, 2checkout

I want to implement 2checkout for my website. I am using a sandbox account and am testing the code on localhost. I have followed this tutorial https://github.com/2Checkout/php-examples.
My code is more or less similar to the one on that page but i keep getting an authorization failed even for credit card information whose response is supposed to be a successful authorization.
Heres my view that has the form

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <h2>Checkout</h2>
       </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="myCCForm" action="<?php echo base_url().'two_checkout/sale';?>" method="post">
<input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="order_id" name="order_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $order_id;?>">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2">
        <span>Card Number</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
    <input class="form-control" id="ccNo" type="text" size="20" placeholder="Debit/Credit Card Number" value="" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2">
        <span>Expiration Date (MM/YYYY)</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
    <select class="form-control" id="expMonth" required>
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="01">Jan</option>
            <option value="02">Feb</option>
            <option value="03">Mar</option>
            <option value="04">Apr</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">June</option>
            <option value="07">July</option>
            <option value="08">Aug</option>
            <option value="09">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
          </select>
    </div>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" size="2" id="expYear" placeholder="Year" required>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-2"">
        <span>CVV</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
    <input class="form-control" id="cvv" size="4" type="text" value="" placeholder="Security Code" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Pay Now">
  </form>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Heres my sale method that handles the post data

```
public function sale(){        

    $order = $this->order_model->getOrderById($this->input->post('order_id'));

    if(!$order) redirect('home');

    // Your sellerId(account number) and privateKey are required to make the Payment API Authorization call.
    Twocheckout::privateKey('my private key');
    Twocheckout::sellerId('my seller id');

    // If you want to turn off SSL verification (Please don't do this in your production environment)
    Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);  // this is set to true by default

    // To use your sandbox account set sandbox to true
    Twocheckout::sandbox(true);

    try {
        $charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
            "merchantOrderId" => $this->input->post('order_id'),
            "token" => $this->input->post('token'),
            "currency" => 'USD',
            "total" => number_format($order['total'],2)

        ));
           if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') {
            echo "Thanks for your Order!";
            echo "<h3>Return Parameters:</h3>";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($charge);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    } catch (Twocheckout_Error $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }


}//end method sale
```

I did a vardump on in the sale method just to make sure the token and order_id were not empty and they were in deed not empty, so the data is being posted correctly. Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The form must also pass in the buyer’s name, email, and full billing address. This is because i am using inline checkout. Found the solution to my problem after reading the [2checkout documentation](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/inline-checkout/) more

```
 "billingAddr" => array(
        "name" => 'Testing Tester',
        "addrLine1" => '123 Test St',
        "city" => 'Columbus',
        "state" => 'OH',
        "zipCode" => '43123',
        "country" => 'USA',
        "email" => 'example@2co.com',
        "phoneNumber" => '555-555-5555'
    )
```